# Pre-processing, resampling and pipelines - and an error in between

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, encoding, pipeline

I have a dataset with different type of variables: binary, categorical, numerical, textual.

```
 Text                                                  Age      Type           Link           Start    Passed  Default
0 care packag saint luke cathol church wa ...           21.0    organisation    saintlukemclean <2001.0 0   0
1   opportun busi group center food support compan...   23.0    organisation    cfanj           <2003.0 0   0
2   holiday ice rink persh squar depart cultur sit...   98.0    home            culturela       >1975.0 0   0
```

I have used different transformers, one for categorical (OneHotEncoder), one for numerical (SimpleImputer) and one for text variables (CountVectorizer/TF-IDF):

```
categorical_preprocessing = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
# categorical_encoder =  ('CV',CountVectorizer())

numeric_preprocessing = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'))
])

# CountVectorizer
text_preprocessing_cv =  Pipeline(steps=[
    ('CV',CountVectorizer())
]) 

# TF-IDF
text_preprocessing_tfidf = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('TF-IDF',TfidfVectorizer())       
])
```

to transform my features and passing them in pipelines (with classifiers Logistic Regression, Multinomial Naive Bayer, Random Forest and SVM) as follows:

```
preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('text',text_preprocessing_cv, text_columns)
        ('category', categorical_preprocessing, categorical_columns),
        ('numeric', numeric_preprocessing, numerical_columns)
])
```

However, I have got an error at this step:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessing),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression())])

clf.fit(X_train, y_train) # <-- error
```

> ValueError: Selected columns, ['Age','Default'] are not unique in
> dataframe.

This error might be caused because of my oversampling or because of my way to pre-process features ... The right order for the resampling should be applying it only to the train set to avoid overfitting, but it is not clear to me if I need to consider the different types of variables and the transformers before/after resampling.

I would appreciate if you could help me in fixing the error, letting a pipeline working using those preprocessing. Thanks

Please refer to the code:

````
text_columns = ['Text']
    categorical_columns = ['Type', 'Link','Start']
    numerical_columns = ['Age','Default'] # can I consider the boolean as numerical?
            
          
        
    X = df[categorical_columns + numerical_columns+text_columns]
    y=  df['Passed']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)
            
     
    # Returning to one dataframe
    training_set = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1) # need for re-sampling technique
          
    passed=training_set[training_set['Passed']==1]
    not_passed=training_set[training_set['Passed']==0]

    # Oversampling the minority 
    oversample = resample(passed, 
                           replace=True, 
                     

  n_samples=len(not_passed),

# Returning to new training set
oversample_train = pd.concat([not_passed, oversample])
    
 train_df = oversample_train.copy() # this train set is after applying the re-sampling
 test_df = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)

X_train=train_df.loc[:,train_df.columns !='Passed']
y_train=train_df[['Passed']

categorical_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
numerical_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'))
])
text_transformer_cv =  Pipeline(steps=[
    ('cntvec',CountVectorizer())
]) 
 

# TF-IDF
text_preprocessing_tfidf = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('TF-IDF',TfidfVectorizer())       
]) # TF-IDF
       
preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=
    [('category', categorical_encoder, categorical_columns),
     ('numeric', numerical_pipe, numerical_columns), # I think this is causing the error. But I do not know why not also categorical columns
     ('text',text_transformer_cv, text_columns)
])

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessing),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression())])

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   
```
````

Comment: You should use some transformation to get a numeric representation of your text data. You can try different combinations of text trasnformations, or even use few jointly, it depends on your data. In my AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised I'm using Tf-idf transformation. You can also give a try to AutoML

Comment: I think it is generating duplicates columns?

Comment: how is it generating? If I print preprocessing it returns the same columns. Also, it is not clear to me why it is currently duplicating only numeric features and not others (maybe it will give me the same error also for the others, after fixingthhat one for numerical, who knows :) Or maybe there is something wrong in the steps or in the order I am considering them

Comment: Can you share what `train_df.columns` and `train_df.dtypes` gives?

Comment: `train_df.columns= Index(['Text','Type', 'Link','Start','Age','Default', 'Label'],
      dtype='object')` and `train_df.columns: Text=object, Age=float64, Type=object, Link=object, Start=object, Passed=float64, Default=int64)`

Comment: Can you try passing your text data as string and not list `text_columns = 'Text'`

Comment: Thanks Prayson W. Daniel. It seems that in this way: `preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('text',text_preprocessing_cv, 'Text'),
        ('category', categorical_preprocessing, categorical_columns),
        ('numeric', numeric_preprocessing, numerical_columns)
], remainder='passthrough')` works!

Comment: I will add that answer then, so we could close this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the way a single text column is passed. I hope future version of scikit-learn would allow `['Text',]` but until then pass it directly:

```py
...

text_columns = 'Text' # instead of ['Text']

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('text', text_preprocessing_cv, text_columns),
        ('category', categorical_preprocessing,
            categorical_columns), 
        ('numeric', numeric_preprocessing, numerical_columns)
    ],
    remainder='passthrough'
)
```